# custom non-JCR magnolia content app with sqlcontainer contentContainer, can't inject ContentConnector or EventBus to the action definition

Tags: jakarta-ee, magnolia

i am working on a non-JCR custom content app for magnolia 5.5.4, i created a container like this:

```
public class ArticlesContainer extends SQLContainer {

    public ArticlesContainer(QueryDelegate delegate) throws SQLException {
        super(delegate);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
}
```

and a treePresenter where i initialize the container like this :

```
public Container initializeContainer() {
        JDBCConnectionPool pool;
        ArticlesContainer container = null;
        try {
            pool = new SimpleJDBCConnectionPool("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver", "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/pfeapp", "admindxbIwZL", "HduX7BJJaBAD");
            QueryDelegate tq = new TableQuery("articles", pool);
            container =  new ArticlesContainer(tq);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return container;
    }
```

until now all fine, it works perfect.
The problem, is when i try to create an action, for example, i added the action AddArticleAction like this :

```
public class AddArticleAction<T extends AddArticleActionDefinition> extends AbstractAction<T>{

    private ContentConnector contentConnector;

    private EventBus eventBus;

    @Inject
    public AddArticleAction(T definition, @Named(AdmincentralEventBus.NAME)EventBus eventBus) {
        super(definition);
        this.eventBus = eventBus;
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void execute() throws ActionExecutionException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

when i click on the add article link in the browser action bar, i get this exception :

> 2017-05-20 00:28:22,321 ERROR fo.magnolia.ui.contentapp.browser.BrowserPresenter: An error occurred
>   while executing action [addArticle]
>   info.magnolia.ui.api.action.ActionExecutionException: Action execution
>   failed for action: addArticle     at
>   info.magnolia.ui.api.action.AbstractActionExecutor.execute(AbstractActionExecutor.java:64)
>     at
>   info.magnolia.ui.contentapp.browser.BrowserPresenter.executeAction(BrowserPresenter.java:347)
>     at
>   info.magnolia.ui.contentapp.browser.BrowserPresenter.onActionbarItemClicked(BrowserPresenter.java:306)
>     at
>   info.magnolia.ui.actionbar.ActionbarPresenter.onActionbarItemClicked(ActionbarPresenter.java:205)
>     at
>   info.magnolia.ui.actionbar.ActionbarViewImpl$1.actionTrigger(ActionbarViewImpl.java:67)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   com.vaadin.event.ListenerMethod.receiveEvent(ListenerMethod.java:508)
>     at com.vaadin.event.EventRouter.fireEvent(EventRouter.java:198)     at
>   com.vaadin.event.EventRouter.fireEvent(EventRouter.java:161)  at
>   com.vaadin.server.AbstractClientConnector.fireEvent(AbstractClientConnector.java:1008)
>     at
>   info.magnolia.ui.vaadin.actionbar.Actionbar.access$000(Actionbar.java:59)
>     at
>   info.magnolia.ui.vaadin.actionbar.Actionbar$1.onActionTriggered(Actionbar.java:72)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   com.vaadin.server.ServerRpcManager.applyInvocation(ServerRpcManager.java:158)
>     at
>   com.vaadin.server.ServerRpcManager.applyInvocation(ServerRpcManager.java:118)
>     at
>   com.vaadin.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleInvocation(ServerRpcHandler.java:437)
>     at
>   com.vaadin.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleInvocations(ServerRpcHandler.java:408)
>     at
>   com.vaadin.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleRpc(ServerRpcHandler.java:273)
>     at
>   com.vaadin.server.communication.UidlRequestHandler.synchronizedHandleRequest(UidlRequestHandler.java:90)
>     at
>   com.vaadin.server.SynchronizedRequestHandler.handleRequest(SynchronizedRequestHandler.java:41)
>     at
>   com.vaadin.server.VaadinService.handleRequest(VaadinService.java:1414)
>     at com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet.service(VaadinServlet.java:365)
>     at
>   info.magnolia.ui.admincentral.AdmincentralVaadinServlet.service(AdmincentralVaadinServlet.java:131)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)     at
>   info.magnolia.cms.filters.ServletDispatchingFilter.doFilter(ServletDispatchingFilter.java:148)
>     at
>   info.magnolia.cms.filters.AbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(AbstractMgnlFilter.java:85)
>     at
>   info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:79)
>     at
>   info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:81)
>     at
>   info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:81)
>     at
>   info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:81)
>     at
>   info.magnolia.cms.filters.CompositeFilter.doFilter(CompositeFilter.java:65)
>     at
>   info.magnolia.cms.filters.AbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(AbstractMgnlFilter.java:85)
>     at
>   info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:79)
>     at
>   info.magnolia.cms.filters.VirtualUriFilter.doFilter(VirtualUriFilter.java:69)
>     at
>   info.magnolia.cms.filters.AbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(AbstractMgnlFilter.java:85)
>     at
>   info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:79)
>     at
>   info.magnolia.module.cache.executor.Bypass.processCacheRequest(Bypass.java:58)
>     at
>   info.magnolia.module.cache.executor.CompositeExecutor.processCacheRequest(CompositeExecutor.java:67)
>     at
>   info.magnolia.module.cache.filter.CacheFilter.doFilter(CacheFilter.java:220)
>     at
>   info.magnolia.cms.filters.AbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(AbstractMgnlFilter.java:85)
>     at
>   info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:79)
>     at
>   info.magnolia.cms.i18n.I18nContentSupportFilter.doFilter(I18nContentSupportFilter.java:74)
>     at
>   info.magnolia.cms.filters.AbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(AbstractMgnlFilter.java:85)
>     at
>   info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:79)
>     at
>   info.magnolia.cms.filters.RangeSupportFilter.doFilter(RangeSupportFilter.java:77)
>     at
>   info.magnolia.cms.filters.AbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(AbstractMgnlFilter.java:85)
>     at
>   info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:79)
>     at
>   info.magnolia.cms.security.BaseSecurityFilter.doFilter(BaseSecurityFilter.java:57)
>     at
>   info.magnolia.cms.filters.AbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(AbstractMgnlFilter.java:85)
>     at
>   info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:79)
>     at
>   info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:81)
>     at
>   info.magnolia.cms.security.SecurityCallbackFilter.doFilter(SecurityCallbackFilter.java:84)
>     at
>   info.magnolia.cms.filters.OncePerRequestAbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestAbstractMgnlFilter.java:59)
>     at
>   info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:79)
>     at
>   info.magnolia.cms.security.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:94)
>     at
>   info.magnolia.cms.filters.OncePerRequestAbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestAbstractMgnlFilter.java:59)
>     at
>   info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:79)
>     at
>   info.magnolia.module.site.filters.SiteMergeFilter.doFilter(SiteMergeFilter.java:119)
>     at
>   info.magnolia.cms.filters.AbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(AbstractMgnlFilter.java:85)
>     at
>   info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:79)
>     at
>   info.magnolia.cms.filters.MultiChannelFilter.doFilter(MultiChannelFilter.java:83)
>     at
>   info.magnolia.cms.filters.AbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(AbstractMgnlFilter.java:85)
>     at
>   info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:79)
>     at
>   info.magnolia.module.cache.filter.GZipFilter.doFilter(GZipFilter.java:73)
>     at
>   info.magnolia.cms.filters.OncePerRequestAbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestAbstractMgnlFilter.java:59)
>     at
>   info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:79)
>     at
>   info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:81)
>     at
>   info.magnolia.cms.security.auth.login.LoginFilter.doFilter(LoginFilter.java:127)
>     at
>   info.magnolia.cms.filters.AbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(AbstractMgnlFilter.java:85)
>     at
>   info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:79)
>     at
>   info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:81)
>     at
>   info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:81)
>     at
>   info.magnolia.cms.filters.ContentTypeFilter.doFilter(ContentTypeFilter.java:155)
>     at
>   info.magnolia.cms.filters.AbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(AbstractMgnlFilter.java:85)
>     at
>   info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:79)
>     at
>   info.magnolia.cms.filters.ContextFilter.doFilter(ContextFilter.java:128)
>     at
>   info.magnolia.cms.filters.AbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(AbstractMgnlFilter.java:85)
>     at
>   info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:79)
>     at
>   info.magnolia.cms.filters.CompositeFilter.doFilter(CompositeFilter.java:65)
>     at
>   info.magnolia.cms.filters.AbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(AbstractMgnlFilter.java:85)
>     at
>   info.magnolia.cms.filters.SafeDestroyMgnlFilterWrapper.doFilter(SafeDestroyMgnlFilterWrapper.java:107)
>     at
>   info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterDispatcher.doDispatch(MgnlFilterDispatcher.java:67)
>     at
>   info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlMainFilter.doFilter(MgnlMainFilter.java:108)
>     at
>   info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlMainFilter.doFilter(MgnlMainFilter.java:94)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:624)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:498)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:796)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1368)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) Caused by:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   info.magnolia.objectfactory.CandidateParameterResolver.resolveParameter(CandidateParameterResolver.java:78)
>     at
>   info.magnolia.objectfactory.ObjectManufacturer.resolveParameter(ObjectManufacturer.java:166)
>     at
>   info.magnolia.objectfactory.ObjectManufacturer.resolveParameters(ObjectManufacturer.java:143)
>     at
>   info.magnolia.objectfactory.ObjectManufacturer.newInstance(ObjectManufacturer.java:86)
>     at
>   info.magnolia.objectfactory.guice.GuiceComponentProvider.newInstanceWithParameterResolvers(GuiceComponentProvider.java:121)
>     at
>   info.magnolia.objectfactory.guice.GuiceComponentProvider.newInstance(GuiceComponentProvider.java:107)
>     at
>   info.magnolia.ui.api.action.AbstractActionExecutor.createAction(AbstractActionExecutor.java:90)
>     at
>   info.magnolia.ui.api.action.AbstractActionExecutor.execute(AbstractActionExecutor.java:61)
>     ... 107 more

I realy don't understand where the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

What do you set as `implementationClass` in your `AddArticleActionDefinition`? It needs to point to `AddArticleAction`. I suspect it doesn't, hence the `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException` exception. Executor can't invoke your action because it's not set.